# base pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, dynamic

Suppose there are `Base` class and `Derived` class.

```
Base *A = new Base;
```

Here A is a pointer point to Base class, and `new` constructs one that A points to.

I also saw

```
Base *B = new Derived;
```

How to explain this?
B is a pointer to `Base` Class, and a `Derived` class constructed and pointed by B?
If there is a function derived from `Base` class, say, `Virtual void f()`, and it's been overridden in `Derived` class, then

```
B->f()
```

will invoke which version of the function? version in `Base` class, or version that overridden in `Derived` Class.

What if there is a new function `void g()`in `Derived`, is `B->g()` going to invoke this function properly?

One more is, is

```
int *a = new double;
```

or

```
double *a = new int;
```

legal?

Comment: Google `polymorphism`

Comment: virtual is a keyword, it is not 'Virtual'. It makes polymorphism work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First question, since inheritance means that `Derived` "is a" `Base`, then a `Derived` is a kind of `Base`, so it makes sense for a `Base *` to be able to point at it.

When you call `B->f()`, you'll get the version of `f()` defined by `Derived`, not the version defined by `Base` (unless `Derived` doesn't actually redefine it). This (along with references) is the primary means of getting this polymorphic behavior in C++.

Second question, if `Derived` defines a function `g()` that is *not* also a member of `Base`, then you just won't be able to call it through a `Base *`. When calling functions through a `Base *`, you can only call those functions which are provided by the interface to `Base`. If `Base` defined a function `g()` which was *not* `virtual`, then you'd get the `Base` version of that function, not the `Derived` version, even if `Derived` redefined it.

Third question:

```
int *a = new int;
```

is legal, but:

```
int *a = new double;
```

since neither `int` nor `double` are classes, so obviously `double` is not derived from `int`.

Comment: a typo, 3-(2) is( double *a = new int;)
but I assume is illegal based on your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`What if there is a new function void g()in Derived, is B->g() going to invoke this function properly?`

You can invoke it thus:

```
//! cast to derived if b really is base of derived
derived* d= dynamic_cast<derived*>(b);
//! d is 0 if b is not a base of derived
if(d)
  d-> g();
```